# ExpressJs - Mongoose: Delete documents with Many To Many relationship

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've two Models, Post and Tag with Many To Many relationships.

**Post Schema:**

```js
const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'A post must belong to a user.'],
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      unique: [true, 'A Post already exists with this title.'],
      required: [true, 'A Post must have a title.'],
    },
    slug: { type: String, unique: true },
    body: { type: String, required: [true, 'A Post must have a body.'] },
    coverImage: String,
    images: Array,
    isDraft: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isPublished: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    tags: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: { currentTime: () => Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
)
```

**Tag Schema:**

```js
const tagSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    slug: { type: String },
    posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: { currentTime: () => Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
)
```

***Now I want to remove all the references of the Posts from the Tag documents when a Post is deleted.***

I'm trying to the following `remove` middleware in the Post model but it is not working. The post get deleted but the reference still there on the Tag documents.

```js
postSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
  var post = this
  post
    .model('Tag')
    .update(
      { posts: { $in: post.tags } },
      { $pull: { posts: post._id } },
      { multi: true },
      next
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many times I finally fired out what wrong I was doing. Following the fix I made to make it work:

In Post Controller I was previously doing this:

```js
const post = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
```

Which I changed to:

```js
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)
await post.remove()
```

And in Post Model:

```js
postSchema.pre('remove', async function (next) {
  await this.model('Tag').updateMany(
    { posts: this._id },
    { $pull: { posts: this._id } },
    { multi: true },
    next
  )
})
```